Kotlin Multiplatform Plugin not installing
Using Android Studio I've been trying to install Kotlin Multiplatform Plugin. But the installation keeps failing.
I've attempted to install from the Marketplace and it throws this error:

The I've tried to download it and install from the disk and get this error:

It seems this creates (several) folders in my Temp folder. I've deleted them and tried to resume installation from disk but it still doesn't work

I'm using Ladybug 2024.2 Patch 2 and Kotlin Compiler 2.0.0 (there was a question/answer that spoke about Kotlin Compiler, unsure if it's useful or not)
I've no idea what am I doing wrong. Thank your for your time and help.

This might not be the best answer, but at least it worked.
I'v downloaded the plugin directly, and found out where are the plugins installed. Unziped it and copied there.
I opened Android Studio and I was able to see the KMM plugin. I then got an error about KMP being incompatible in K2 mode and I just went to Settings searched for K2 mode, and unchecked it.
I believe I restarted my Android Studio and ran the app and it seemed to work. I'll later do more work on the app and check if everything's actually running properly.
